# Get rows with a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

Each customer can have one or multiple accounts (`account_id`)

How can I get max `closed_date` for the customers who closed all their accounts and the rest of the active customers?*

*active customers are the ones with at least one open account.

```
+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| customer_id | account_id | created_date | closed_date |
+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 3eba3       | 5dddd      | 17/06/2020   |             |
| 3eba3       | eabbd      | 29/06/2020   |             |
| 3eba3       | 9f3a4      | 29/06/2020   | 09/11/2020  |
| 5hlf1       | khti1      | 01/02/2020   |             |
| hdk12       | sfsf2      | 05/03/2020   | 01/06/2020  |
| hdk12       | sfsl3      | 06/03/2020   | 01/10/2020  |
| 12kju       | gege1      | 07/03/2020   | 01/07/2020  |
| 12kju       | mhfl1      | 08/03/2020   | 03/07/2020  |
+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

**Desired output:**

```
+-------------+-------------+
| customer_id | closed_date |
+-------------+-------------+
| 3eba3       |             |
| 5hlf1       |             |
| hdk12       | 01/10/2020  |
| 12kju       | 03/07/2020  |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `distinct on` for this:

```
select distinct on (customer_id) t.*
from t
order by customer_id, closed_date desc nulls first;
```

This returns one row per `customer_id` based on the `order by` clause.

Comment: Nice approach. Some suggestions: it is an inefficient practice to use t.* in a query (for smaller databases: psql, mysql).

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and a `case` expression:

```
select customer_id,
    case when bool_and(closed_date is not null) then max(closed_date) end as closed_date
from mytable
group by customer_id
```